# Call a local variable in some other function : Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I'd like to call a variable, lets say `var cow;` which is placed in the function `function farm()` in the function `function milk()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cow
function farm() {

cow = Math.Random;

}

function milk(){

// call/return value of cow

}
</script>
```

Check out this link: [GLOBAL VARIABLES IN JAVASCRIPT by Snook](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable)
.
Now if you see the last code carefully, and test it...it actually doesn't work, but I want something similar to work. You can check the code below...

```
var myValue;
function setValue()
{
    myValue = "test";
}

function getValue()
{
    alert(window.myValue); // yup, it's "test" (original) ---> (after testing) No its "undefined"
}
```

Comment: And does your test work or not? What do you get if you test for the existence & value of the variable? Anything? Not sure based on your message whether you have a problem. If I ever have to do anything like that, I declare a GLOBAL variable outside of any functions, in the wide open, like so: var myValue; and then I simply keep referring to myValue in other functions. It works (but it's not recommended).

Comment: @ShawnSpencer : I get undefined...tried it many times...but still its "undefined"

Comment: @tunetosuraj - Your original statement is correct, `cow` will be global.  However, you're probably looking for `Math.random()` and not `Math.Random` (which is undeclared and thus undefined)..  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Thanks buddy.. I'm sorry I missed your answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to your example you can declare cow in the global scope:

```
var cow;

function farm() {

  cow = Math.random();

}

function milk(){

  // call/return value of cow

}
```

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/FTt5D/; pay attention random is a method, you must use parenthesis () and write it in lowercase.

Comment: Dude you figured out what I was missing... :) well thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

What you have will actually work, as `cow` will be `hoisted` to the enclosing scope (which, in this case, is global).  It might not work because the function is actually `random()`, not `Random()`, and it's a function not a variable - Try this:

```
function farm() {
   cow = Math.random();
}

function milk(){
   // call/return value of cow
   alert(cow);
}

farm(); //Init cow
milk(); //call milk
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `cow` in the global scope:

```
var cow;

function farm() {
  cow = Math.Random;
}

function milk() {
  // call/return value of cow
}
```

But I'm now sure how this differs from your second example. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Nope. done that already...doesn't work...Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably have more code. Can you post it? This code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kLgwU/4/

Comment: In the second example, as it was stated on snook's site,...here `window.somevariable` is used...which is used to fetch a global variable...but that is not working for me